# SQL: How to query all data within the month from the given date?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `tbl1` of `ID` Numbers and their corresponding Membership Date.

I want to create a `stored procedure` which has a `@member_date` parameter provided. I want the procedure to get the **month and year** of **@member_date** to get all the records covered **by the month and date**

```
ID_Number   Member_Date
10001        12/1/2015
10002        12/15/2015
10003        10/9/2015
10004        12/13/2014
```

Something like below:

```
@member_date = '12/25/2015'
Select * from tbl1 where month(Member_Date)=12 and year(Member_Date)=2015
```

Output:

```
ID_Number   Member_Date
10001        12/1/2015
10002        12/15/2015
```

Thank you for your help
Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still I am not getting you proper, but I think you want something like below,

```
CREATE TABLE RYANTABLE (ID_NUMBER  INT, MEMBER_DATE DATE)
INSERT INTO RYANTABLE VALUES (10001,'12/1/2015')
INSERT INTO RYANTABLE VALUES (10002,'12/15/2015')
INSERT INTO RYANTABLE VALUES (10003,'10/9/2015')
INSERT INTO RYANTABLE VALUES (10004,'12/13/2014')
```

You need store procedure right like below ?

```
--EXEC RyanProcedure '12/25/2015' 
CREATE PROCEDURE RyanProcedure
    @member_date DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MONTH AS INT=MONTH(@member_date)
    DECLARE @Year AS INT=YEAR(@member_date)

    SELECT *
    FROM   RyanTable
    WHERE  (MONTH(Member_Date) = @MONTH  
           AND YEAR(Member_Date) = @Year)
           OR (Member_Date = @member_date)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
DATE_FORMAT(<date>, <date_format>)
```

for example

```
SELECT * FROM TBL1 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Member_Date, '%Y%m') = '201512'
```

%Y  Year, numeric, four digits,

%m  Month, numeric (00-12)

for date format, you can see in [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Comment: the value of **Member_Date** is **'12/25/2015'** in this case **DATE_FORMAT('12/25/2015', '%Y%m')** return **null**

Comment: i think, if Member_Date is varchar it will return null, but if Member_Date is date format it will not return null. and its different result if you type DATE_FORMAT('12/25/2015', '%Y%m') with DATE_FORMAT(Member_Date, '%Y%m')

Answer (score 0):

You should make your query [Sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) for best performance

```
DECLARE @member_date date= '12/25/2015'

SELECT *
FROM
  tbl1
WHERE 
  Member_Date >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @member_date), 0)
  Member_Date < dateadd(month, datediff(month, -1, @member_date), 0)
```